# Resharper bug when referencing silverlight assembly from CLR class library

Tags: silverlight-4.0, resharper, resharper-5.x

I'm starting with a new application using silverlight and the first problem I have with Resharper is in my unit test project.

My configuration is:

-> Resharper 5.1.1727.12

-> MyProject.Tests (CLR 4.0)

- nunit.framework.dll (CLR 2.0)
- moq.dll (CLR 4.0)
- MyProject.Silverlight (Silverlight 4.0)

The test project compiles, no errors and the tests run fine in Reshaper, NUnit Gui, TestDriven.Net

The problem I have is that Resharper keeps telling me to import the System.dll version 2.0 (red line under all silverlight assembly objects/methods like a compiler error, but the project compiles).

The complete message is:

“Module ‘System. Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e’ should be referenced.”

I believe the problem is not related to tests, but that resharper is getting lost when mixing CLR 4.0 and Silverlight 4.0 assemblies.

Is there a way to get rid of this annoying message?

Thanks,

André

**EDIT:
Steps to reproduce**:

1. create a silverlight 4 class library
2. add a class Foo that extends INotifyPropertyChanged
3. create a CLR 4 class library and reference the silverlight class library
4. add any class and declare a Foo object as a field or whatever

The project will compile, but resharper will tell you need to import System.dll v2.0.

If you disable resharper, no error message is displayed.

**EDIT2:**
Installed resharper 5.1.1751.8, no success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created bug request and you are welcome to monitor its status at 
youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-191461
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post. Please accept out apologies for the bad experience you have had with our tools. I' m going to reproduce this ASAP and let you know about the status.

UPDATE: We have fixed this in R# 6.0 EAP builds. We are not able to backport it to R# 5.1.x

Comment: Hi, I'm suffering from this problem as well. Is there any update on a timeframe for resolution? I've had to disable all code inspection in the meantime.